# Make html page design using div and span

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to make a design as described in the image [image]

I have used the following code but it's not working well. Please help!

Problem is that the Q and A text will be in a box and the size will be increased automatically as more text comes in the box.

```
<div style="font-family: Arial,serif;font-size: 10.6px;color: rgb(68,68,68);font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;text-decoration: none">
    <span style="font-weight:bold;height:30px;width:30px;background-color:aqua;display:inline;">
                Q
    </span>
    <span style="font-family: Arial,serif;font-size: 10.6px;color: rgb(68,68,68);font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;text-decoration: none;display:inline;">
                Date of birth
    </span>
</div>
<div style="font-family: Arial,serif;font-size: 10.6px;color: rgb(68,68,68);font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;text-decoration: none">
    <span style="font-weight:bold;height:30px;width:30px;background-color:blueviolet;display:inline;">
                A
    </span>
    <span style="font-family: Arial,serif;font-size: 10.6px;color: rgb(68,68,68);font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;text-decoration: none">
                02/08/2019 11:05 - 14/01/1991 (John Doe)
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a `display:table-row` and `display:table-cell` CSS properties

```html
<div style="display:table-row;font-family: Arial,serif;font-size: 10.6px;color: rgb(68,68,68);font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;text-decoration: none">
  <span style="display:table-cell;font-weight:bold;height:30px;width:30px;background-color:aqua;">
    Q
  </span>
    <span style="display:table-cell;font-family: Arial,serif;font-size: 10.6px;color: rgb(68,68,68);font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;text-decoration: none;">
    Date of birth
    <br/><br/>
    test
  </span>
</div>
<div style="display:table-row;font-family: Arial,serif;font-size: 10.6px;color: rgb(68,68,68);font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;text-decoration: none">
    <span style="display:table-cell;font-weight:bold;height:30px;width:30px;background-color:blueviolet;">
      A
    </span>
    <span style="display:table-cell;font-family: Arial,serif;font-size: 10.6px;color: rgb(68,68,68);font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;text-decoration: none">
      02/08/2019 11:05 - 14/01/1991 (John Doe)
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thought about using the ::before selectors? (I separated the css for tidyness)

```
<style>
div.q,
div.a {
    color: rgb(68,68,68);
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 45px;
}

div.a div::before,
div.q div::before {
    bottom: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    left: 0;
    padding: 20px 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    width: 30px;
}

div.q div::before {
    background: aqua;
    content: 'Q';
}

div.a div::before {
    background: blueviolet;
    content: 'A';
}

h2 {
    margin-top: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
}
</style>

<div class="q">
    <div>
        <h2>Please choose the best description</h2>
        <p>Please choose smoker if you have used any tobacco...</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="a">
    <div>
        <h2>02/08/2019 11:05 - 14/01/1991 (John Doe)</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5{margin:0px;}
.main{
width:100%;
height:auto;
}
#question-part {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
display: -webkit-flex;
-webkit-flex-direction: row; 
display: flex;
flex-direction:row;
}

.ques-left {
width:40px;
text-align:center;
background-color:lightgrey;
height: auto;
}
.ans-left {
width:40px;
text-align:center;
background-color:grey;
line-height:40px;

}

#answer-part {
width: 100%;
line-height: auto;
display: -webkit-flex;
-webkit-flex-direction: row; 
display: flex;
flex-direction:row;
}
.ques-right{
width:100% ;
margin:3px;
text-align:justify;
}

.ans-right{
width:100% ;
margin:3px;
line-height:40px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

<div id="question-part" >
<div class="ques-left">Q</div>
<div class="ques-right" >
  <h2>Please Type Your Question Here</h2><br>
  <h3>Please choose the best description of your smoking</h3><br>
  <h4>Please choose if you have used any tobacco products </h4>
  <p>options:non-smoker,smoker</p>
</div>
</div>

<div id="answer-part">
<div class="ans-left" >A</div>
<div class="ans-right">02/08/2019 11:05-Smoker(John Doe)</div>
</div>
</div>
```